# Adding results of two functions JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with returning the values of two functions and adding them together. I need to add fruitNum to carNum

HTML

```
<select class="fruit" >
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Orange</option>
  <option value="3">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="4">Banana</option>
</select>

<select class="car">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){

 $('.fruit').change(function(){
    fruitNum = $(this).val();

});

 $('.car').change(function (){
    carNum = $(this).val();

 });

 Something adding both values fruitNum and carNum     
});
```

Thanks for help

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/szymondzumak/764W9/58/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have dynamic update of the values, you can create a "callback" function that will be fired each time one of the select is changed. By using the javascript parseInt function you can convert the selected value in an integer and perform a mathematical sum.

```
$(function(){

 $('.fruit').change(function(){
    fruitNum = $(this).val();
    clback();
});

 $('.car').change(function (){
    carNum = $(this).val();
    clback();
 });
//callback function that performs the add
    function clback(){
     result = parseInt($('.car').val()) + parseInt($('.fruit').val());
     console.log(result);
    }
});
```

here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/764W9/60/)

Comment: Perfect! That sorted it for me. Need to read more about callbacks for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

in your script $(this) is not the selected option, it is the SELECT input, so you have to change your selector this way:

```
$('.fruit').change(function () {
    alert($(this).find(':selected').val());
    alert($(this).find(':selected').text()) //for content
});
```

Select control adds the pseudo class :selected to the currently selected option

Cheers!

Comment: Have a look at the updated fiddle. Selector is ok. I have a scoping problem I guess. Can't return the result of .val and add them together. I think. Thanks for time

Comment: No worries. Cheers anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
var fruitNum, carNum, sum; //you have to declare variables

 $('.fruit').change(function(){
    fruitNum = $(this).val();

});

 $('.car').change(function (){
    carNum = $(this).val();

 });

 function getFruitAndCarSum(){ 
    return fruitNum + carNum;
 };
});
```

By calling `getFruitAndCarSum()` you should get what you want.

Comment: When pasting in to the JSFiddle I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. So deosnt work for me yet. Cheers for time will try to make it work.

Comment: $ is the reference to jQuery if you paste it into new JSFiddle and don't select jQuery it has every reason to show this exception :-) Cheers!

Comment: Ok but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Dzięki;) Link do Fiddla
http://jsfiddle.net/szymondzumak/4TN8K/

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function addSelects()
{
    return parseInt($('.fruit').val()) + parseInt($('.car').val());
}
```

If you need to call this function on select change, then call it on the event listener

```
$('.fruit').change(function()
{
    console.log(addSelects());
}
```

Same for `$('.car')`

Comment: I think the idea is similar to this one and it works:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856472/adding-results-of-two-functions-jquery/21856667#21856667

Thanks for time ! :)